# Redgate source control - how to tell which repository of a Git repo that the Db is linked to?

Tags: redgate

My team is using redgate source control for our databases with Git.  I noticed that as I was looking at the database, it wasn't obvious which source control path eg.  which branch it was linked to in SSMS.  Where can I see this setting?
You can see the branch name when you start a commit, but where can I see the full path - because there several different Git repos that we use.

[update]
ok, nevermind, it has been a while since i had to use it.  An "update" message hiding the source control menu across the top of the window in ssms.  Once I clicked on my update and installed it, the source control menu was visible again.  I was able to see the folder where branch pointed to.